# How can I update variable in NodeJS runtime?

Tags: node.js, json, child-process

I have an API that is giving data based on local JSON files. I have another function called `scrapeData` is scheduled to run every minute using `scheduledJob` in NodeJS. This function locally updates the local JSON files based on the scraped data.

After scraping is done, I am wondering how I can update the global variables that contains JSON so that I can serve updated JSON files to users.

Below code is what I came up with but seems like it's not working when it comes to updating the existing variables

I am using NodeJS with express and expecting to update the variable in run time.

index.js

```js
// Local data files
let boyGroupJSON = require("./asset/boy-group.json");
let girlGroupJSON = require("./asset/girl-group.json");
let idolJSON = require("./asset/idol.json");

// Schedule Job for fetching data
const scheduledJob = schedule.scheduleJob("0 * * * * *", () => {
    scrapeData("boy-group");
    scrapeData("girl-group");
    scrapeData("idol");

    // Below variables are not updated :( 
    boyGroupJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/boy-group.json"));
    girlGroupJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/girl-group.json"));
    idolJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/idol.json"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that when using `require()`, NodeJS is caching the files.
Use `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("PATH"));` instead.

Here's the fixed code:

```
// Local data files
let boyGroupJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/boy-group.json"));
let girlGroupJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/girl-group.json"));
let idolJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/idol.json"));

// Schedule Job for fetching data
const scheduledJob = schedule.scheduleJob("0 * * * * *", () => {
    scrapeData("boy-group");
    scrapeData("girl-group");
    scrapeData("idol");

    // Below variables are not updated :( 
    boyGroupJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/boy-group.json"));
    girlGroupJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/girl-group.json"));
    idolJSON = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./asset/idol.json"));
});
```